# Using Jupyter for teaching -- hiding output

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I want to give a lecture on using a jupyter notebook. I've entered my code as "in:" and tested it generating "out:".  I don't want to have the outputs visible until after I hit return on an input when presenting, so the students can see it in action. How do I save the current file so when I open it no outputs are visible? (Note that this is different than hiding the output, such as with a semicolon.)

Comment: "I recently watched a webinar in which @rxin clear the results from the Javascript Console (in Chrome)

View -> Developer -> JavaScript Console

and then type "notebook.clearResults()" " from: https://forums.databricks.com/questions/1833/how-do-i-clear-all-output-results-in-a-notebook.html

Comment: Why not simply *delete* the outputs before the lecture? (Cell -> All Output -> Clear)

Comment: I didn't know about (Cell -> All Output -> Clear) but now I do! Thanks Gregor.

Answer (score 0):

As Gregor commented the solution is simple, once you know it: simply delete the outputs  (Cell -> All Output -> Clear)

I'm posting this here since it wasn't obvious to me even after a bunch of searching, although I am a newcomer to Jupyter.